# How to delete last element in a 2d array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an array in through form .I am using explode method to separate my values

```
$getData =$_POST['jasonHandle'];

print_r($getData); // output   incoetp,11,12,13,#,101,11,12,#
```

here # is used for separation

```
$arr=explode(",#,",$getData);

print_r($arr);    // Array ( [0] => incoetp,11,12,13 [1] => 101,11,12,# )
```

The above array may contain any number of elements(in this case  there are tow arrays) .

I need to delete this # element which is appearing at last of last array

I tried unset() and array_pop () ,but its deleting entire last array .

Also *COUNT()* function is not working for inner array

```
echo count($arr[1]);   //  Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

I have been using count function for 2 d array and never had any issue .why is this happening?

Comment: It's a string. Just trim it, like: `trim($arr[1], ',# ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

you can use chop() function

chop()--> The chop() function removes whitespaces or other predefined characters from the right end of a string

```
$arr[1]=chop($arr[1],",#");
```

Comment: This does work .thanks .How do I get counts of inner arrays .

echo count(arr[1]) 
gives me error  //count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: What happens if you use `strlen($arr[1])`?

Comment: simply use this `count(explode(",",$arr[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Delete it by using `rtrim`

$arr[1] = rtrim($arr[1], '#');